# Cannot find symbol: javac no longer compiles my driver file when classes are placed in a package

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package, classpath, javac

noob here.

I have a group of class files which are used by a driver file. I originally wrote the files without any package statement and compiled the files using:

```
javac -d classes src/Driver.java
```

Driver compiled without a hitch (though I had to add the path to the src directory in my .bash_profile CLASSPATH variable first)

Next, I added a package statement at the top of all my src files. The statement had the form:

```
package edu.school.course.project;
```

Every src file got the same package statement. However the javac command now yields 62 "cannot find symbol" errors when executed. Every Driver.java reference to another class file in my src directory fails.

I tried adding this import statement to each class file that extends or implements some parent class in the package:

```
import edu.school.course.project.*;
```

Still, javac yields 62 "cannot find symbol" errors.

Do I need to modify my CLASSPATH variable to include the package? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is create a directory to hold your Driver class.  For instance:

```
mkdir -p src/edu/school/course/project
mv src/Driver.java src/edu/school/course/project
```

Then compile it:

```
javac -d classes src/edu/school/course/project/Driver.java
```

You can put all your other related Java files in that same directory.

Assuming Driver has a main() method, to run it:

```
java -cp classes/ edu.school.course.project.Driver
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed all my problems

Answer (score 2):

Delete the old binary class files from your filesystem (the files in `classes`). Next, re-run the above compile. You do not need the `import` statement(s) if everything is in the same package. Modify your `CLASSPATH` to include the `classes` directory (not your `src` directory). Finally, run the driver as `java edu.school.course.project.Driver`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I've removed all the binary files from my classes directory. I even superstitiously deleted and recreated the classes directory. Brand spankin new. I'm running up against the same problem: nothing was fixed. 

I removed all the package statements and ran the above javac command to make double sure I remembered the past correctly. Good news is that my memory is correct. The files really do compile when they aren't in a package. :( Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: @Austin Have you moved the files into sub-directories matching their new package structure? The compiler is going to look for the classes with their fully qualified names.

Comment: I haven't. Current path to the files is ~/Project/src Are you saying I should reorganize it like ~/Project/src/edu/school/course/project/